# How to create a key binding that inserts text in the Fish shell

Tags: fish

I would like to save typing in the Fish shell by binding a key to a text. When I press the key, the text should be inserted into the shell. The effect should be the same as typing that text.

One of the problems is that the text should not be executed, just inserted. The closest I came is this experiment where the text "whoami" is inserted when I press Alt+G:

```
bind \eg "echo -n whoami"
```

However, when I press enter the command is not executed, so the effect is not the same as typing the text directly in the shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to modify the *commandline*, which incidentally is possible with the `commandline` builtin.

```
 bind \eg "commandline -i whoami"
```